# hp dl380p gen 8 bios

Tags: linux, redhat, hp, bios

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm not use to enterprise hardware.

I have the job of patching one of our servers while our main person is out.  I patched it, but the server wouldn't boot and after trying a few things I realized it was the bios and went into setup and told it to use the backup rom of the bios.  I need to double check to make sure it was the bios and not something else that I did by mistake.

I want to know if I go ahead and try again that the backup rom of the bios is safe.

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:  When updating I'm getting it can't read drive(Can't find C drive).  This server is a specialized red hat from a vendor.

Update 2:  I manage to grab an image
[error message received after firmware update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuwJE.jpg)

Comment: What error are you getting? It's uncommon for a BIOS upgrade to prevent an HP server from booting.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to put that in, I'm getting it can't read drive(Can't find C drive)

Comment: Red Hat Linux doesn't use a C drive. Can you post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Sorry I can't, I got the server fixed to a previous state, but I'm going to be trying the steps again tomorrow so maybe if it breaks it again I can post one.  I do release linux doesn't use a c drive like windows does so I did find it weird.

Comment: I added a screen shot, it seems to be breaking on a firmware update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure the underlying issue, but the answer to the question is yes the bios will be safe.

When updating bios the active bios gets put in the backup bios and the updated bios is put in the current bios.

When switching to backup bios it becomes current and what is in the current gets put in the backup slot.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please remove any USB, SDHC or virtual devices from the server and attempt boot again.

This is a Linux server. There's no `C: drive` in Red Hat Linux.

Comment: There is an external hard drive attach to it so we can remotely do a backup or restore to the server.  By hitting F11 I can pick that one and it will boot the backup drive, but when telling it to boot from the main hard drive I get this message, but I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: I test out your suggestion, but doing a boot without the drive connect I still got the same message.  When booting and picking HDD and USB Drive (drive not connected) I get Read Error only.

Answer (score 0):

The `Attempting Boot From Hard Drive (C:) - Read Error` message comes from BIOS. HP (and Compaq before it) historically wrote their BIOS error messages in a DOS/Windows-centric way. It just means it's trying to boot from whatever is set as the primary boot disk, and failing.

As J Doe said in his answer, trying the backup BIOS is safe.

I would recommend taking any necessary steps to check the health of your system disk(s), just in case. By the symptoms it might be that your system disk is dying, particularly if this was a first reboot in a long time.

There may even be a correlation, but it does not necessarily imply causation. If the disk consistently works with the old BIOS but fails with the new one, it might mean the new BIOS version has something wrong with it that causes the failure in accessing the disk. Or it might just mean the new BIOS has more strict criteria for disk health than the old one (shorter timeouts, perhaps?) and you should take this as an early warning that your system disk might be about to die soon.

You should also check the BIOS release notes: your system has a built-in HP Smart Array P420i hardware RAID controller. There might be a requirement to update the hardware RAID controller firmware (separate from the BIOS) to a specific version before upgrading the BIOS. A mismatch in versions could cause the BIOS to fail to access the RAID controller, and thus fail to boot.